# Finding a system of linear equations with 4 solutions given

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am really struggling here and dont know where to start.

Let $P_1 = (1,-1, 2,  0), P_2 = (0,-2,-1, 0),
P_3 = (2, 0, 1, 2), P_4 = (1, 2, 0, 4)$.

Find a system of linear equations so that $P_i$ are solutions of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Delta\neq0$, which gives the  linear independence.

Thus, $P_1+P_1+P_3+P_4=(4,-1,2,6)$ your system, for example.

Comment: Ohhh yes thank you alot